How to send object data in hx-post - JSON.stringify is surrounding arrays with quotes
I'm trying to send data via REST API from a client to a server, the client is just an HTML page with JavaScript and HTMX in it, the server is Spring Boot. The endpoint accepts POST requests with an object:
public record FileMetadataDTO(Integer availabilityTime, FileDTO[] files) {}
public record FileDTO(String name, String extension, Integer sizeMB) {}
On the client side I have a button that sends the request to the server:
    <button id="upload-button"
                    hx-post="http://localhost:8080/api/v1/upload/metadata"
                    hx-headers='{"Content-Type": "application/json"}'
                    hx-ext="json-enc"
                    hx-vals='js:{"availabilityTime": 1, "files": getFilesDTO()}'
                    style="display: none;">Upload</button>
            <label for="upload-button" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 6px 12px; cursor: pointer;">Upload files</label>

The getFilesDTO() function returns a stringified array:
function getFilesDTO() {
            let filesDTO = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < tuckedFiles.length; i++) {
                filesDTO.push({
                    name: tuckedFiles[i].name,
                    extension: tuckedFiles[i].name.split('.').pop(),
                    sizeMB: tuckedFiles[i].size / 1024 / 1024
                });
            }
            return JSON.stringify(filesDTO);
        }

But JSON.stringify surrounds the array with quotes and the server cannot deserialize it:
{"availabilityTime":"1","files":"[{\"name\":\"a.txt\",\"extension\":\"txt\",\"sizeMB\":0.00022220611572265625},{\"name\":\"another_file.txt\",\"extension\":\"txt\",\"sizeMB\":0.000003814697265625}]"}

A valid payload would be:
{"availabilityTime":"1","files":[{"name":"a.txt","extension":"txt","sizeMB":0.00022220611572265625},{"name":"another_file.txt","extension":"txt","sizeMB":0.000003814697265625}]}

But I can't make JSON.stringify do it like that no matter what. I tried it in the console of Chrome and Edge to see if my code is at fault, but JSON.stringify([]) in the console of both browsers returns '[]'.
How can I fix this? I've been on multiple websites and can't find a solution.

My guess would be that you are serializing the files in the payload twice, once in the getFilesDTO, and another time when the payload is send to the server. Try removing the JSON.stringify from your getFilesDTO function and see if it helps.

This usually happens when you already stringified the files array, and then it gets stringified again later.  I suggest trying return filesDTO

That is true. I stringify them in getFilesDTO function and then json-enc stringifies them again. But if I don't stringify them in getFilesDTO then the files property will be  "[object Object]"`.

That should not be happening if you only JSON encode it once. Can you please edit the question to show the code which handles the response of the call to getFilesDTO() and creates the JSON that is actually sent in the request

Where do you first see "[object Object]"? Is there another step in here that may need to be modified to account for the array returned by getFilesDTO ()?

@RoryMcCrossan I don't have any more code, the hx-vals='js:{"availabilityTime": 1, "files": getFilesDTO()}', then I think the json-enc evaluates it. This is where I import json-enc from https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.12/dist/ext/json-enc.js
@mykaf I only see "[object Object]" in the request's payload, even though my function returns an array, not "[object Object]", so my guess would be that maybe json-enc is doing something wrong, but then I have no control over that because it's an external library.

I don't use htmlx, but it looks like it expects that functions in hx-vals return strings. If the value of getFilesDTO() isn't a string, it calls toString(), which turns objects into [object Object].

@Barmar even If I hard code an array like this hx-vals='{"availabilityTime": 1, "files": [{"name": "x", "extension": "txt", "sizeMB": 5}]}' it still sends "[object Object]".

That's quite strange. Seems like it only allows properties to be strings, not nested properties.

"A valid payload would be:" that's not valid JSON though. You can't have an escaped quotation mark outside of a string from which it is escaped.

@HereticMonkey you are right, it would not work with escaped quotation mark.

How about you simply return JSON.stringfy({availabilityTime: 1, files: filesDTO}) from your function, instead of building a complicated literal in hx-vals?

@deceze because I'm using HTMX which creates the request on button click based on button's attributes, hx-vals allows me to add parameters to the request. The thing is, I'm doing this project to get used to HTMX.

I don’t really know HTMX, but if you can call a function in hx-vals which must return a string, then simply return the complete JSON payload from the function, instead of only part of it.

https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/issues/966

@deceze I tried what you said, hx-vals='js:{...getPayload()}', getPayload() returns an object with two properties (the ones described in the post) but it still sends files property as "[object Object]".

Alright, I updated the json-enc from 1.9.12 to 2.0.1, apparently what's on their (HTMX) website is an older version, I got it from GitHub. Now I can send a proper request, but only with one file, otherwise I get this error:
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON     --> starting at object with constructor 'Array'     --- index 2 closes the circle
This json-enc really doesn't like arrays, seems like. I'm trying to debug now.

This is what it sends when I get the error above: availabilityTime=1&files=%22%5Bobject%20Object%5D%22&files=%22%5Bobject%20Object%5D%22, instead of an array, the files property is present twice. Don't know why.

Just hx-vals='js:getPayload()', with the function returning JSON.stringify(…) doesn’t work…?

@deceze nope, VM1408:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}', it wants an object, even if I return an object with getPayload(). I tried hx-vals:'js:...getPayload()' and I'm back to the circular reference error.
Also, if I return JSON.stringify(...) it sends an object with each character from the actual payload as an object property, e.g. 0:"{"1:"\""2:"a"3:"v"4:"a"5:"i"6:"l"7:"a"8:"b"9:"i"10:"l"11:"i"12:"t"13:"y".

It may be that you have not imported the json-enc extension.
But also whatever is returned from getFilesDTO() is what is added to the payload, so don't return a string if you don't want a string!
If I replicate the code, adding an explicit import (after the htmx import), it works ok.
express server
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        ...
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org/dist/ext/json-enc.js"></script>

getFilesDTO()
    <script>
      // dummy files for testing 
      const files = [
        {name: "abc.js", size: 100 * 1024 * 1024},
        {name: "def.js", size: 200 * 1024 * 1024}
      ]
      function getFilesDTO() {
        return files.map((file) => {
          return {
            name: file.name,
            extension: file.name.split('.').pop(),
            sizeMB: file.size / 1024 / 1024
          }
        })
      }
    </script>

In the console network tab, it shows a non-quoted files array


Alternatively you can <script> in the json-enc code (it's quite small) and use that to debug
    <script>
      htmx.defineExtension('json-enc', {
        onEvent: function (name, evt) {
          if (name === "htmx:configRequest") {
            evt.detail.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json";
          }
        },
        
        encodeParameters : function(xhr, parameters, elt) {
          console.log('parameters', parameters)
          xhr.overrideMimeType('text/json');
          return (JSON.stringify(parameters));
        }
       });
    </script>


This is it. This is what works. I was importing:

<script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@2.0.2/dist/htmx.js"             integrity="sha384-yZq+5izaUBKcRgFbxgkRYwpHhHHCpp5nseXp0MEQ1A4MTWVMnqkmcuFez8x5qfxr"             crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx-ext-json-enc@2.0.1/json-enc.js"></script>

I changed them to what you provided and it works. Strange, because I took those imports from HTMX website.
Edit: Sorry, I don't know how to format this to look pretty. Thank you for your answer!
